Dymola FMU generation - Array Dimensions are always local constants in the FMU
I have an issue when dealing with arrays in my models.
Expected/desired behaviour:
I want to export an FMU with array dimensions as fixed parameters which I could modify before initializing the simulation.
Observed behaviour:
When I export the model the array dimension has causality = local, variability=constant and is thus not modifiable.
Test code:
model ArrayDimExample

  parameter Integer N = 5 "array dimension";
  Real A[N] "my array";

equation 

  for i in 1:N loop
    A[i] = i;
  end for;

end ArrayDimExample;

Software Version: Dymola 2024x Refresh 1, 2024-04-12
FMU export settings:

Type: Model Exchange + Co-Simulation
Version: 3.0 (I also tried 2.0 with same results)

Active flags:

Include source Code
Export with string parameters
Copy resources to FMU
Show dialog when exporting
Evaluate False on Export Parameter (I also tried with this flag off, same results)


@janpeter: I do not think that the example above is about "variables structure" of a model, but just changing size of arrays.
FMI 3.0 supports this, see https://fmi-standard.org/docs/3.0.1/#fmu-variables.
(FMI 2.0 has no array support, there is only the "structured naming convention" that in fact serializes an array, where the size is fixed)
The "N" in your example is a structural parameter in the sense of FMI 3.0. It is up to the exporting tool, if this structural parameter has "variability"= constant, fixed or tunable.
The question what is supported by Dymola in the current release has to be answered by some Dymola expert. Best ask your Dymola support if noone answers here.

Interesting with FMU 3.0. I just googled up a tool that translate Python code to FMU 3.0 and in this way an FMU could likely be made that solves the problem. Here is the link https://pypi.org/project/pythonfmu3/ :)

Thank You for your contribution. I contacted Dymola support and they will likely implement variable size arrays through the new FMI 3.0 standard from the first release of 2025.

I am pretty sure the answer is no. This problem I would call "variable structure" problem and there has for many years been an interest to handle these in Modelica. There is a little bit written about it in the Modelica language specification, appendix B, see
https://specification.modelica.org/master/
A recent paper from 2022 on an extension of Modelica to handle variable structure is the following that might be of interest.
https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1665221/FULLTEXT01.pdf
However, the Modelica language allow you to make models with matrix sizes that are set just before translation. The FMU is then made from the translated model.
(The technique to specify sizes of state vectors etc just before translation, are used a lot in the Modelica Standard Library for Fluid and Media, for instance).
If here is any opening for your specific problem in recent versions of Modelica software and latest FMU 3.0, perhaps someone else can confirm my no.

Starting in Dymola 2025x, there is support for dynamic parameter arrays that can be initialized at runtime. This means that a vector or matrix of arbitrary size can be read at simulation initialization into a Modelica parameter.
parameter Real p[:] “Vector of unknown size” 
     annotation(__Dymola_UnknownArray=true);

And yes, it works for FMU generation too.
For more explanation see https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/external-parameter-sets-modelica-dag-br%C3%BCck-4x5sf/?trackingId=2rLqHBIRSWSoUIUn4RkKoQ%3D%3D.
